# How can I send an array with the index.html file. How to access it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

I want to know if there is a way to send an array from the index.html to another external js File with express.js.

Server.js

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    app.use(express.static("./animeCatcher"));
    res.sendFile("index.html");
})

app.get("/anime", (req, res) => {
   let animeNames = ["One Piece", "Fairy Tail", "Attack on Titan"];
   res.json(animeNames);
        });
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src= "animeScrape.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

animeScrape.js

```
fetch('/anime')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(animeNames => console.log(animeNames));
```

I try to explain it as detailed as possible.

When I start my express Server(server.js) it starts by opening the Port 8000 and the url("/") loads the html file first.

Because of the linked script file in my index.html the animeScrape.js tries to fetch the Array, which i didnt sent yet.

When i go to the url("/anime") then it sends the Array to the Browser which will be displayed, but in order to access this Array I need to send the index.html 
file again with the Array. Then my animeScrape.js will be loaded again and has something to fetch.

I hope that makes everything clear.

Thanks in Regards

Comment: Client-side, `fetch('/anime').then(res => res.json()).then(animeNames => console.log(animeNames))`. Replace `console.log` with a function that does whatever you need to do with the array.

Comment: Also you don't need to `res.json(JSON.stringify(animeNames));`, `res.json(animeNames);` already stringifies the object before sending the response, otherwise you're double-encoding the response and you'd need to double-parse it on the client.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I tried your method, but it didnt work. Because after the html file is loaded by the Server ('/') the other(client-side) js-file is also loaded because they are linked together.
The Problem is it tried to fetch something which i didnt send yet. 
And altough i get to my "/anime" page, it shows me just the Array on the Browser and in the Console is nothing logged

Comment: It doesn't sound like my suggestion is related to your problem at all. You need to serve the rest of your resources properly first before you can start dealing with this problem.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts i added more detailed information. That are all my files and i hope it will  help.

Comment: `app.use(express.static("./animeCatcher"));` needs to be top-level, not inside `app.get()`

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts, didnt know that. But still fetch wont log me anything.
So to be clear the fetch method has to be inside animeScrape.js